# Geekdocs HUGO template not compatible with blogdown

Tags: r, markdown, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to create my own version of the [Geekdown HUGO website][1].
I'm starting a new project through the RStudio add-in and I'm including `thegeeklab/hugo-geekdoc`as a theme. However, when it's all loaded, serving the site will instantly break with the following error message repeated:

```
ERROR 2021/01/13 14:13:02 render of "page" failed: execute of template failed: template: _default/single.html:5:7: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "head" .>: error calling partial: "D:\Stefan\Gradient\Repositories\handbook\themes\hugo-geekdoc\layouts\partials\head.html:18:29": execute of template failed: template: partials/head.html:18:29: executing "partials/head.html" at <index .Site.Data.assets "main.min.css">: error calling index: index of untyped nil
```

To reproduce, this is all that's needed:

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = 'thegeeklab/hugo-geekdoc')
```

I haven't encountered an error like this before using blogdown, hugo and other themes.
[1]: https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-geekdoc/

Comment: I know what's wrong in this case (the repo itself is not a full theme, and the complete theme lives in the Github releases). I'll post an answer later. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. One from the theme, and one from **blogdown**. [The **blogdown** bug was just fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/876543da95d25ebcef16c005dfbdc8dd1fbabe02). The problem with the theme is that the Github repo itself is not a complete Hugo theme, and there are extra files that need to be built. According to [its documentation](https://geekdocs.de/usage/getting-started/), you have to either download the full theme from its Github releases, or build it by yourself (using `gulp`).

With the dev version of **blogdown**, which you can install via

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

you can install this theme from its Github releases (remember to restart R after you install **blogdown**, before you try the code below):

```r
blogdown::new_site(theme = 'https://github.com/thegeeklab/hugo-geekdoc/releases/latest/download/hugo-geekdoc.tar.gz')
```

There is one minor problem with the theme in Github releases, though. That is, it doesn't contain the `exampleSite` folder. Unless you are familiar with the theme, or have read its documentation carefully, I'd suggest you copy the files and folders of [its `exampleSite` folder](https://github.com/thegeeklab/hugo-geekdoc/tree/master/exampleSite) into the root directory of your new website, before you run `blogdown::serve_site()` to preview the site. Without this step, the site works fine, but it will only contain a single sample post from **blogdown**.

Comment: This is great Yihui, worked like a charm!